# Django. Загрузка файла из формы. Проблемы с валидацией

Tags: python, django, валидация

Вроде тема довольно заезжаная, и довольно много материала написано по этому вопросу, но что-то не срастается. 
Необходимо: загрузить файл из формы на странице, обработать и сохранить в другой файл/добавить в БД. Без разницы особо. Остановимся на варианте с сохранением промежуточным в файл.

forms.py

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False)
    file = forms.FileField()
```

views.py

```
def uploadFile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/success/url/')
    else:
        form = UploadFileForm()
    return render_to_response('upload/main.html', {'form': form})


def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    destination = open('addfile', 'wb+')
    for chunk in f.chunks():
        destination.write(chunk)
    destination.close()
```

Все обрабатывается, ошибок никаких не вылезает, но и ничего не происходит вместе с тем. Проблема заключается в том, что программа не заходит в if с валидацией.

Сама форма:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload/uploadFile" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="addfileids">Добавить файл </label>
    <input id="addfileids" type="file" name="addfileids">
    <button type="submit" value="Добавить", class="btn btn-primary">Добавить</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Естественно, у вас же в форме нет поля с именем `file`.

Comment: Добавьте {{ form }} в шаблон, тогда должно работать. Если хотите вручную добавлять поля формы, то посмотрите какие id у полей формы, которая отображена самим Django и укажите такие же.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте так

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload/uploadFile" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label>Добавить файл </label>
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <button type="submit" value="Добавить", class="btn btn-primary">Добавить</button>
    </form>
```